# How to moq a service call in a method which is returning an object of abstract class?

Tags: c#, .net, nunit, moq

I want to MOQ a service call in method for which I am writing unit test methods.

For example:

```
public void MethodUnderTest(data)
{
   XYZService.ServiceMethod(data);
}
```

The above service method returns an object of an abstract class(Lets say ClassA). i.e

```
    public ClassA ServiceMethod(ClassA data)
    {
         //code
    }


 public abstract class ClassA
    {
         //Code
    }
```

Now, if I write moq for above test in my test class as :

> _xyzService.setup(x => x.ServiceMethod(data)).Returns(**?**);

If I write **new ClassA()** in place of **?**, I am not supposed to do that as class is abstract!

So, What should I place in Return?

Comment: If you return anything which derives from `ClassA` it will be correct approach. Just create dummy `public class ClassAB : ClassA`.

Comment: @Fabio The purpose of a mocking-framework is exactly to *not* create all those derivates yourself but to rely on the framework to create instances of those types.

Comment: @HimBromBeere, my comment's point was that OP need return only class derived from `ClassA`. How he will create this instance it doesn't metter from test point of view. Sorry I didn't try to discriminate importance of mocking framework :)

Comment: As it seems `ServiceMethod` doesn´t return anything so you can´t use `Setup(...).Returns(...)`. But without knowing what this method does we can´t say how to mock it or if you even need to.

Comment: ServiceMethod is returning an object of classA, I cannot mention what is exact data inside these methods due to security conserns

Comment: Your code for `MethodUnderTest` doesn´t use the return-value of this method at all. This was why I assumed it to return nothing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You´re not creating a mock-instance:

```
var mock = new Mock<ClassA>();
_xyzService.Setup(x => x.ServiceMethod(data)).Returns(mock.Object);
```

`new Mock` just creates a class deriving from `ClassA` and returns an instance of that class.

Comment: @Vishwas Eeeehm can you elaborate? Where?

Comment: @Vishwas - do not use `copy-paste` :)

Comment: It is working when I derived a class(ClassB) from ClassA and pass to Return method, but when I implemented above code, I get syntax error in Returns(mock), says, "cannot resolve method 'Returns(Moq.Mock<XYZNamespace.ClassA>)"

Comment: I think you need `mock.Object` which contains the actual instance. See my code.